# openssl .so library version incompatible

Tags: openssl, opendkim, libraries

I upgraded to openssl-1.1.1d from openssl-1.0.0
But, opendkim supports openssl-1.0. So, some changes were done and compiled it.
The compiling was okay. 
When I try to run the binary, sometimes it runs. But, mostly the following error occurred.

> libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (libopendkim.so.10). No file or directory named libcrypto.so.10

So I created a symlink file libcrypto.so.10 pointing to libcrypto.so.1.1, but the following error occurred.

> libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (libopendkim.so.10)

I could not get through this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which os and version you are using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I want it to work in all recent OS versions.